# How can a Chrome extension get a user's permission to use user's computer's microphone?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, google-chrome-app

If we run HTML5's Web Speech API's JavaScript codes below in a website on a Chrome, Chrome will ask for user's permission for the use of user's computer's microphone.

```
var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
recognition.start();
```

But if I run codes above on a Chrome extension's page, Chrome doesn't ask users to give a permission. How can a Chrome extension get a user's permission to use user's computer's microphone?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you have to implement it yourself. In chrome extension's manifest.json, there is a permissions parameter. I think first you have to get the permission to use microphone in that file. I don't know what is the parameter called but you can check that in the documentation.

This permission warning is shown only when the user installs the extension. After that, the extension can turn microphone on/off at its volition. To seek permission from user, first check which website user is using and if you want to activate the microphone on that. After that, just inject HTML/CSS code in that webpage that will show a popup to user asking for her permission. If the permission is yes, send the message to background page and then just turn it on.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can't find the permission I need on page https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html. I don't seek to get permission of use of mic on a website. I seek to ask users to give permission of use of mic on a Chrome extension's page.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `navigator` global object to ask for audio and/or video permission in your JS file of your chrome extension:

```
navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true})
```

although MDN says it's [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) you can use this instead:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})
```

---

Check [this tutorial](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) as well for some alternatives to JS.