# Chrome Extension: accessing mic by Speech Recognition call

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, speech-recognition

Before you read this, it may be related to 
[How can a Chrome extension get a user's permission to use user's computer's microphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858258/how-can-a-chrome-extension-get-a-users-permission-to-use-users-computers-micr)
I've added an answer below, including code and my manifest, if that helps.

I am writing a minimal Chrome Extension (using Chrome 75.0.3770.90 on MacOS 10.14.5) to implement a 'listen' button for my accessibility project. I've written an HTML version with the JavaScript which works the microphone.

However, when I lift that code into the Extension background.js file, the text-to-speech works, but not the speech-to-text. The code runs, but the flashing mic never appears in the tab.

The code which works is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
        <h2>All-in-one JavaScript Example</h2>
        <button onclick="myCode();">Listen</button> 
        <script>
            window.SpeechRecognition = window.webkitSpeechRecognition 
               || window.SpeechRecognition;

            function myCode() {
                recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
                recognition.start();
                recognition.onresult = function(event) {    
                if (event.results[0].isFinal) {
                    response = event.results[0][0].transcript;
                    synth = window.speechSynthesis;
                    synth.speak( new SpeechSynthesisUtterance( 
                        "i don't understand, "+response
                    ));
            }   }
            alert( "all-in-one: we're done!" );
        }
        </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Minimal reproducible example:

```
    {
        "name": "myName",
        "description": "Press to talk",
        "version": "0.97",
        "manifest_version": 2,
        "background": {
            "scripts": ["background.js"],
            "persistent": false
        },
        "permissions": ["contentSettings","desktopCapture","*://*/*","tabCapture","tabs","tts","ttsEngine"],
        "browser_action": {
            "default_icon": "images/myIcon512.png",
            "default_title": "Press Ctrl(Win)/Command(Mac)+Shift+ Down to speak"
        },
        "commands": {
            "myCommand": {
                "suggested_key": {
                    "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Down",
                    "mac": "Command+Shift+Down"
                },
                "description": "Start speaking"
            }
        },
        "icons": {
            "512": "images/myIcon512.png"
        }
    }
```

My background JavaScript is:

```
    window.SpeechRecognition = window.webkitSpeechRecognition || window.SpeechRecognition;

    function myCode() {
        var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
        recognition.onresult = function(event) {
            if (event.results[0].isFinal) {
                var synth = window.speechSynthesis;
                synth.speak( new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(
                        "sorry, I don't understand."
                    )
                );
            }   
        }
        recognition.start();
        alert( "extension: we're done!" );
    }
    chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
        if (command === 'myCommand')
            myCode();
    });
```

I've also noticed that the code only runs once - I can keep on clicking in the listen button, but the Extension command only runs once (putting in an alert at the beginning of the function only gets displayed the first time around)

The default on my browser is that it should ask (once) which it does on the HTML version.

Thanks, just for reading this far! I've put an answer, with code, below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had is that the mic seems to be a background task, whereas I'm trying to interact with tab contents.  I don't think this is usual, and have ended up with a generic 'matches' value (`*://*/*`) in my manifest (in full):

```
{ "name": "Enguage(TM) - Let's all talk to the Web",
  "short_name" : "Enguage",
  "description": "A vocal Web interface",
  "version": "0.98",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["kbTx.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    { "matches" : ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["tabRx.js", "interp.js"]
  } ],
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "contentSettings",
    "desktopCapture",
    "tabCapture",
    "tabs",
    "tts"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/lbolt512.png",
    "default_title": "Press Ctrl(Win)/Command(Mac)+Shift+ Space and speak"
  },
  "commands": {
    "enguage": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Space",
        "mac": "Command+Shift+Space"
      },
      "description": "single utterance"
  } },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/lbolt16.png",
    "48": "images/lbolt48.png",
    "128": "images/lbolt128.png",
    "512": "images/lbolt512.png"
} }
```

I think Google might not like this! Anyway, I have put in a keyboard listener in my background code (`kbTx.js`):

```
    chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
        if (command === 'enguage') {
        // find the active tab...
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            //send it a message...
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
                tabs[0].id,          // index not always 0?
                null, // message sent - none required?
                null                 // response callback - none expected!
                //function(response) {console.log("done" /*response.farewell*/);}
                );
            });
        }
    });
```

And I've put in a context script which listens for this message (`tabRx.js`):

```
    window.SpeechRecognition = window.webkitSpeechRecognition || 
                                window.SpeechRecognition;

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
            var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
            recognition.start();
            recognition.continuous = false;
            recognition.onresult = function(event) {
                if (event.results[0].isFinal) {
                    window.speechSynthesis.speak(
                        new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(
                            interp( event.results[0][0].transcript )
                    )   );
        }   }   }
    );
```

The message listener essentially contains the code in the `allInOne.html` example above.
There may be other ways of doing this, but this works and seems reasonably lightweight.
Hope this helps.

Please feel free to add comments to this, if you think I can improve my code!